# /etc/bashrc Permission denied

Tags: bash, centos-5

It's that simple:

```
root@server [/etc]# touch /etc/bashrc
touch: cannot touch '/etc/bashrc': Permission denied
```

OS: Linux

Distro: CentOS

Release: 5.3

Extras: cPanel installed

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Have you managed to get into some unusual situation where root isn't root? Do you have a uid of 0?

Comment: Voting to close as this is non-programming related

Comment: Is selinux enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `i` attribute on the file:

```
# lsattr /etc/bashrc
----i------------e- /etc/bashrc
```

If yes, remove it:

```
# chattr -i /etc/bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

1) ls -l /etc/bashrc will show you attributes of the file, maybe its read-only even for root ?

2) Or it could be SELinux that prevents you from "writing" to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The file could be also immutable.  That would be odd.  This is a sign of something wrong or pretty unusual.

Answer (score 0):

See the [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1423740/nginx-says-emerg-11-open-etc-nginx-nginx-conf-failed-13-permission-de).

Finally I got the solution. Its the [SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) mode issue. First I check current SELinux mode.

getenforce
Here is: Enforcing So it needs to be Permissive.

setenforce [Enforcing|Permissive|1|0]
To make changes persistent through a system reboot, edit the 'SELINUX=' line in /etc/selinux/config for either 'enforcing', 'permissive', or 'disabled'. For example: 'SELINUX=permissive'